# Laravel, bind model from json in the request body

Tags: c#, php, json, laravel

In asp.net mvc you can have a json such as

```
{ 
   name: "Victor",
   lastName: "Ionescu"
}
```

and then have a controller

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{

}
```

and the model in C# would be like this

```
public RegisterModel 
{
  public string name { get;set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I fail to see how to do that in laravel?

Comment: You can check route modal binding in laravel. link - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: but i dont care about eloquent models, i want normal plain old php objects, not whatever .